# Gulp with Browserify: Bundle task seems to fail after Delete task when watching

Tags: gulp, browserify

Here are my tasks to delete, bundle and watch for changes. Everytime I bundle, it works fine (even if the file doesn't exist yet). However, with the watch task, it'll break when it deletes the file and won't rebuild. Thoughts?

```
gulp.task('delete', function() {
    var path = 'app/public/bundle.js';
    return del(path);
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['delete'], function() {
    var projectFiles = glob.sync('./app/**/*.js')
    return browserify({
       entries: projectFiles,
       extensions: ['.js']
    })
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function(err){
        gutil.log(err);
    })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/public/'))
    .pipe(notify({message: 'Browserify bundlified!'}))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app/assets/sass/**/*', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.js', ['bundle']);
})
```

Comment: What error it throws? What does the `del` function return? I think it needs to return a stream or a promise in order to work with gulp properly, otherwise it might run i wrong order. See note in https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps

Comment: Apparently, the current version of `del` does return a promise: https://www.npmjs.com/package/del. Are you using the current version of `del`?

Comment: @Martin I actually dont have a JS error, I've realized. It's only a 404 on my bundle.js file that was deleted (and not rebundled). I'll look into the promise.

Comment: @threed. Didn't realize that. I'll look into a promise for it. Thanks